# How to show that saddle point of $f(x,y)=|x|+|y|$ does not exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y)=|x|+|y|$$

Critical points of this function are $\mathbb{R}×{0}$ i ${0}×\mathbb{R}$. (the derivative doesn't exist)

I know that $(0,0)$ is minimum, but what about other critical points?
I can show that, they aren't extremums but it doesn't exclude them from being saddle points.

I have tried to show that using the definition of saddle points but I've failed.

So, how to show that saddle points do not exist?

Thanks

Comment: What's your definition of saddle point?  Some texts use “any critical point that's not an extremum.”

Comment: What's your definition of a saddle point? Does it require the derivative at the point to exist?

Comment: I quote: " $f$ has a saddle point at $(x, y)$ if there is a disk centered at $(x, y)$ such that the following conditions holds: $f$ assumes its maximum value on one diameter of the disk only at $(x , y)$, and assumes its minimum value on another diameter of the disk only at $(x, y)$"

Comment: Oh in that case: pick a non (0,0) critical point. Is there any diameter of a disc for which $f$ obtains its max at that point?

Comment: No there isn't. Will the max be at one of end of the diameter?

Comment: That's right. You'll have to formalize a bit more, but that's the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how to give you up-vote or any other way to appreciate your help. But your answer made me sure that i'm going right.

Comment: Interesting.  So $(x,y)$ is *not* a saddle point if for every disk centered at $(x,y)$ and every diameter of the disk, the maximum and minimum values of $f$ along that diameter are not at $(x,y)$.  Or, for every unit vector u and $\epsilon > 0$, the map $[-\epsilon,\epsilon] \to \mathbb{R}$, $t \mapsto f((x,y) + t u)$ does not have a max or min at $t=0$.

Comment: It is nice way to formalize it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be fixed. For any other point $(x,y)$ nearby, write this point in polar coordinates as $x=x_0+r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=y_0+r\sin(\theta)$. Then
\begin{align}
f(x,y)=f(r,\theta)=|x_0+r\cos(\theta)|+|y_0+r\sin(\theta)|.
\end{align}
When you start with the assumption that $(x_0,y_0)$ is in the first quadrant (and $r$ is sufficiently small), you find $f_r=\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)$ so $f_r=0$ occurs when $\cos(\theta)=-\sin(\theta).$ But then at such an angle, $f=x_0+y_0$. Hence, there are no extrema in any direction, aside from the function being constant along one diameter. By symmetry, the same argument holds in the other quadrants.

You can actually picture the function, as it's an upside down diamond.